# is/are + past participle vs. have been + past particple

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, syntactic-analysis, past-participles

So I am really confused when to use *past participle* and *have been + p.p*

For example

In situations like the ones below

> 1. Are these dishes **washed**?
>      Have these dishes **been washed**?
>      (Washed and the dishes were being dried )
> 2. The boxes **have been taken** away
>      The boxes **are taken** away
>      (Already gone by the time we got there)

Answer (score 1):

'Have been' is usual in this context. 'The boxes are taken away' doesn't sound natural at all.

However, past participles can sometimes be used as adjectives, like 'the dishes are washed'; 'the plate is broken'.